# REGEX: match directory lines

Tags: regex

I have a list of directories:

```
/media/nosthertus/music/oor no scared.mp3
/media/nosthertus/OST/data/music/zone4_1.ogg
/media/nosthertus/OST/data/music/zone4_2.ogg
/media/nosthertus/music/Epic Hybrid _ Alex Moukala - Reborn _ Orchestral Action Rock _ EpicMusicVN.mp3
```

i am not that good with `REGEX` so i have tried to use this expression:

```
/\/(\w+|(\w+\s))\..{3}/g
```

there is a `regex101` session that has more examples on my attempt to match the dirs in [here](https://regex101.com/r/xD5fV4/1)

please explain what have i done wrong..

**EDIT**: i want to match a whole directory which is contained in a string.. for example

```
Some random string text here
/dir/to/folder/or/file.ext   //Match this whole DIR
```

Comment: what are you trying to match? what is the output you want ?

Comment: @rock321987 i have edited the question

Comment: can you clarify what do you want to match in `/media/nosthertus/OST/data/music/zone4_2.ogg`?

Comment: @rock321987 i want to match all of it, you can see in regex101 there are other things that are not dirs, my goal is to use this in a javascript function that will extract all dirs from a string

Comment: is **[this](https://regex101.com/r/xD5fV4/3)** good?

Comment: @rock321987 it is.. post it as your answer and i will mark it as the solution

Comment: well its based on simple  assumption that anything beginning with `/` is directory..it may not be correct assumption though

Comment: @rock321987 for this case is valid as the dirs are separated in different lines from other stuff that are not dirs.. for the time being, this is good enough for me to have a better example and practice REGEX

Comment: well I have extended it a bit more..e.g. if there is only `/abc.html`, I am assuming it to be file not directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match all directories (I am assuming that anything starting with `/` and containing at least one more `/` is directory)

```
^\/[^\/]*\/.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD5fV4/4)**

**or** if you want, you can use

```
^\/.*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD5fV4/3)**